# Any way to create views against a Read-Only SQL Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have access to an SQL server that is set to ReadOnly.  I cannot make schema changes.  I would like to create views to store different queries and such for easy access via python and other code but obviously I cannot.   Is there any other workaround people are aware of? Maybe some way to host the SQL views on a different DB that's not ReadOnly or some other software. Any guidance is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: If you can create view definition in another database on same server, then you just have to use three-part naming scheme (`database.schema.table_or_view_name`) for queried tables and views, should work. We are often using such 'proxy' database for outside access (web and other services) to clearly separate different services and users etc.

Comment: Synonyms work too. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-synonym-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15